# Laravel eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm looking for a way to query an attribute while removing space and making it lower case.

```
Artist Table
artist_id - '1'
artist_name - 'The Big Shot'
```

I want to be able to create the following query

```
Artist::where('artist_name', '=', $request->input('artistname'));
```

Example

```
Artist::where('thebigshot' = 'thebigshot')
```

Comment: BTW if your text-field collation ends with _сi (case insensitive), for example utf8_general_ci then you dont need lower-casing. "WHERE text = 'abc' " and "WHERE text = 'ABC'" will mark the same thing. it have sense if you have case-sensitive collation, for example latin1_general_cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing spaces and lowercasing the string is not a task for Eloquent - it's something that you should do before passing that to the query, e.g.:

```
$name = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $request->input('artistname'));
Artist::where('artist_name', '=', $name)->get();
```

Comment: What if the data is saved in the database as 'The Big Shot' and i want to compare it to 'thebigshot' after lowercasing and removing space?

Comment: First of all, you should normalize your data (lowercase, remove spaces) before saving in the database, otherwise you need to process every returned row for every query + you can't use indexes to find matching rows faster. But, if youm really want to do this, you'll need to normalize string that comes from the request, like in the answer, and compare it with normalized string in the database that you'll calculate on the fly.

Comment: In order to do that, instead of "where" you can find in the answer, do: Artist::whereRaw("LOWER(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')) = ?", array($name))->get();

Comment: Omg perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an other way of doing and you get the same result.
    $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ','', 'the big shot')); //thebigshot
    Artist::where('artist_name', '=', $name)->get();